# Webpack & Three.js canvas rendering

Tags: canvas, three.js, rendering

I have recently converted a project built on Three.js using webpack (which is new for me).
After that, I encounter an issue in rendering a 2D canvas.
Even though I get no errors, the created canvas results in a "huge" black rectangle.

I installed canvas and used it as follows:

```
import {createCanvas} from 'canvas';

let canvas = createCanvas(200, 200);
let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.font = 'Bold ' +18 +'pt ' +'arial';
...
...
let texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
texture.needsUpdate = true;
texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter; 
let material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({map: texture,
                                         transparent: false
                                       });
```

Could you help me, please?

Comment: Why don't you create your canvas like so: `document.createElement( 'canvas' );`?

Comment: I get the same result, even so ...

Comment: I just fixed it as:

let material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({map: texture,
                                                                   transparent: true,
                                                                   opacity: 1
                                                                  });